# Group Legend in Echart

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, vue.js, echarts

I want to group Legend in echarts so that I can position them together. I am not having much luck as the docs are really not that good.

```
option = {
    legend: {
        data:['Legend 1', 'Legend 2', 'Legend 3','Legend 1', 'Legend 2', 'Legend 3']
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Legend 1',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        },
        {
            name: 'Legend 2',
            type: 'line',
            data: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
        },
        {
            name: 'Legend 3',
            type: 'line',
            data: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
        },
        {
            name: 'Legend 1',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        },
        {
            name: 'Legend 2',
            type: 'line',
            data: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
        },
        {
            name: 'Legend 3',
            type: 'line',
            data: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
        }
    ]
};
```

[image: I want result like below image]

I have tried to make legend data like

```
legend: {
        data:[{'group 1':'Legend 1'}, {'group 1':'Legend 2'},{'group 1':'Legend 3'},{'group 2':'Legend 1'},{'group 2':'Legend 2'},{'group 2':'Legend 3'}]
    }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Please post any solution if found.